# Javascript: avoid embedded function calls object multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

I have a JavaScript function that is being called multiple times.  It appears the createUser function gets added as an array and is called each time someone clicks the "Add Bidder" link.

```
<a id="add_bidders_14" class="bidders" href="#" vendor_id="123"> Add Bidder </a>
```

Here is the a Javascript functions

```
function addClickBehavior() {
    $("#add_bidders_14").click( function () {
         var data_object = {};
         data_object.vendor_id = $(this).attr("vendor_id");
         bidderModal() 
    } 
}


function bidderModal(data_object) {
    createUser(data_object); 
}


function createUser(data_object) {
    alert("I pop up more and more each click to the Add Bidder link");
}
```

What I want to happen is that a new createUser function to occur on every click and not create multiple instances of createUser. So in reality the alert will only fire once.

Comment: Could you clarify your bottom paragraph?  What functionality are you looking for?  Just the alert to fire once?

Comment: Oh you mean you are attaching multiple click handlers that all fire at once.

Comment: @JohnStrickler Yes the click handler is firing the createUser multiple times.  If I have clicked the link 5 times the createUser function will fire the alert 5 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

```
 $("#add_bidders_14").unbind().click( function () {...
```